# How to implement a Multi Class Application

Tags: java, class, oop

This is the zoo manager coding:

```
public class ZooManager {
public void feedAnimals(Animals a, Food[] arrayFood) {
    Food temp = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayFood.length; i++) {
        if (arrayFood[i].getFoodName().equals(a.getTypeOfFood())) {
            arrayFood[i].setAmount(arrayFood[i].getAmount() - 1);
            System.out.print("Animal is fed.");
        }
    }
    System.out.print(temp);
}
public void isFoodEmpty(Food[] arrayFood) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayFood.length; i++) {
        if (arrayFood[i] == null) {
            System.out.print("True");
        } else {
            System.out.print("False");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the code for the main application:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ZooApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Animals[] a = new Animals[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter the animal name: ");
        String an = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("What type of food do they eat: ");
        String tof = in.nextLine();
        a[i] = new Animals(an, tof);
    }
    Food[] b = new Food[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter the type of food: ");
        String f = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the amount: ");
        int am = in.nextInt();in.nextInt();
        b[i] = new Food(f, am);
    }
    ZooManager z= new ZooManager();
    System.out.print(z.feedAnimals(a[i], b));
    System.out.print(z.isFoodEmpty(b[i]));
  }
}
```

I have an error at the two final out prints on the main application. The first one is that "the void type is not allowed there." and "variable i can not be found." The second out put says that "isFoodEmpty cannot be given to the type: Food, required: Food[]." Thank you for any advice or help.

Comment: well, feedAnimals ***is*** void so the compiler is right to complain.  What would you like to happen (ie, what should the print function actually print?)

Comment: As for variable 'i' not found, that is because it does not exist outside of the scope of the for loop that creates it.

Answer (score 3):

Your isFoodEmpty function is a void, so the first error is telling you that you can't print it because it doesn't return anything. Second, you are passing an individual instance of Food into a function that is looking for an array.  That's the second error.  Also note that variable i is only defined within the scope of the for loop, so you can't go using it outside of the loop.

Edit:

Currently your isFoodEmpty is a void.  you have one of two options:

```
public void isFoodEmpty(Food[] arrayFood) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayFood.length; i++) {
        if (arrayFood[i] == null) {
            System.out.print("True");
        } else {
            System.out.print("False");
      }
    }
  }
}
[...]
isFoodEmpty(b);    // it already prints within the function
```

or

```
public boolean isFoodEmpty(Food[] arrayFood) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayFood.length; i++) {
        if (arrayFood[i] == null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
      }
    }
  }
}
[...]
System.out.println(isFoodEmpty(b));    // print the boolean that it returns
```

Either way, you might want to check the logic on that function, since it will return empty if even one of the elements in the array is null. (You could have 20 food items, then one null value, and it would return true).